# a more efficient code for creating a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to build a matrix in which the first column of the row is a random value from 1 to 3, the second from 1 to 4 and so to the column number tm-3. I have created the following code to fill the matrix with random numbers

```
tm <- 10
A <- matrix(0, 5, 23)
for(i in 1:5){
  for(j in 1:c(tm-3)){
    A[i,j] <- sample(1:c(j+2), 1, replace = T)
  }
}
A[ ,-c(1:c(tm-3))] <- sample(1:tm, 16, replace = T)
```

This code of course works fine, but the double loop slows down the entire program when large matrices appear.

Is it possible to get rid of the double for and fill the first few columns with random numbers according to the above formula?

Comment: What is the expected output for columns with number larger than `tm-3` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to replace your double loop:

```
sapply(1:(tm-3), function(x) {sample(1:(x+2), 5, replace = TRUE)})

# example output
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    1    1    5    3    3    5    5
# [2,]    2    1    1    1    4    5    2
# [3,]    1    1    3    5    1    1    6
# [4,]    2    1    3    1    7    6    9
# [5,]    2    4    1    1    7    3    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with a single `for` loop - you can do every column all at once by setting the `sample` size to the number of rows:

```
for(j in 1:(tm-3)){
    A[,j] <- sample(1:c(j+2), size = nrow(A), replace = T)
  }
```

And here's a way with no `for` loop, populating each column with maximum allowed value, multiplying by a `runif` value, and taking the ceiling:

```
A[, 1:(tm - 3)] = ceiling(rep(1:(tm - 3) + 2, each = nrow(A)) * runif(nrow(A) * (tm - 3)))
```

You can, of course, follow either of these with the line you have for the rest of the matrix:

```
    A[ ,-(1:c(tm-3))] <- sample(1:tm, 16, replace = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses only a single loop:

```
tm <- 10
B <- matrix(ncol=23,nrow=5)
for (i in seq_len(ncol(B))) B[,i] <- sample(min(i+2,tm),nrow(B),replace=TRUE)
```

The resulting matrix differs from other posted solutions in terms of the elements in the column numbers greater than `tm-3`:

```
#> B
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
#[1,]    1    3    4    6    3    7    5    8    6     6     1     6     9     8     2     6
#[2,]    2    1    3    2    3    5    3    3    7     7     4     5     1     4     9     4
#[3,]    2    1    2    2    2    8    3    3    4     5     8     8     4     6     1     1
#[4,]    2    3    5    2    1    7    5   10    7     3     6     2     1     1     8     4
#[5,]    3    3    2    2    2    1    2    9    4     8     2     9     3     6     1     7
#     [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23]
#[1,]    10     9     2     6     1     4     8
#[2,]     5     4    10     4     6     2     2
#[3,]     2     4     2     1     3     2    10
#[4,]     6     2     2     4     3     5     2
#[5,]     2     9     2     8     2     1     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `lapply` and `do.call(cbind)` to map across the matrix you want to replace. Leaves only `tm` and the matrix as arguments and avoids the odd simplification rules of `sapply`. Wrapping the code inside a function also makes it a lot more reusable.

```r
make_matrix <- function(tm, A){
  A[, 1:(tm - 3)] <- do.call(
    what = cbind,
    args = lapply(
      X = 1:(tm - 3),
      FUN = function(n) sample(1:(n + 2), nrow(A), replace = TRUE)
      )
    )
  return(A)
}
A <- matrix(0, 5, 23)
make_matrix(10, A)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#> [1,]    2    2    2    3    2    8    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
#> [2,]    1    4    4    5    3    3    4    0    0     0     0     0     0
#> [3,]    2    1    5    2    6    2    2    0    0     0     0     0     0
#> [4,]    1    2    2    1    7    7    7    0    0     0     0     0     0
#> [5,]    2    1    4    5    3    4    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
#>      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23]
#> [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [4,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [5,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Created on 2018-07-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that fills with `sapply()` the first tm-3 column with random samples `1:<column number + 2>`. The remaining columns > 7 will be filled via `replicate()` from a sample out of `1:tm` with replacement. In the Function you can define `tm, nrow, ncol` of the resulting matrix.

```
mFun <- function(tm, nrow, ncol) {
  A <- matrix(NA, nrow, ncol)
  A[, 1:(tm-3)] <- sapply(1:(tm-3), 
                          function(x) sample(1:(x + 2), nrow, replace=TRUE))
  A[, - (1:(tm-3))] <- replicate(ncol - tm + 3, sample(1:tm, nrow, replace=TRUE))
  return(A)
  }
```

***Yielding***

```
> set.seed(42)  # for sake of reproducibility
> mFun(tm=10, nrow=5, ncol=12)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    3    3    3    6    7    5    7    9    4    10     4     8
[2,]    3    3    4    6    1    4    8    1    5     9     4     7
[3,]    1    1    5    1    7    8    4    3    1     7     4     2
[4,]    3    3    2    3    7    4    7   10   10    10     8     3
[5,]    2    3    3    4    1    7    1    7    5     7     1     6
```

***Testing***

Runs pretty fast with a 1.000 x 100.000 matrix:

```
> system.time(A <- mFun(10, 1e3, 1e5))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.88    0.92    7.96
```